# Get console.log from Selenium using php webdriver

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to run integration tests against some of our AMP pages to see if they validate. AMP runs validation if you append #development=1 to a URL and puts the results in console.log. I need to be able to read console.log to check this.

This is what I have so far:

```
$caps = DesiredCapabilities::firefox();
$caps->setCapability('loggingPrefs', array('browser'=>'ALL'));

//connect to selenium
$webdriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', $caps);

$webdriver->get('https://www.example.com/amp/page.html#development=1');
sleep(10);
$logs = $webdriver->manage()->getLog('browser');

var_dump($logs);
```

Using Facebook's webdriver for PHP. I can get the logs back, but it doesn't seem to include anything from console.log. How can I capture this data?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the Facebook PHP WebDriver implementation does not seem to implement any of the LoggingPreferences "facilities". However, because PHP is what-I-believe-is-called weakly typed, you can "cheat" by making a call to:

```
$chromeCapabilities->setCapability( 'loggingPrefs', ['browser' => 'ALL'] );
```

And then later, call (say)

```
var_dump( $chromeDriver->manage()->getLog( 'browser' ) );
```

to access the console log.
The following is a working sample I used to get this working after about 30 hours of investigation - I hope it helps someone! It can use Selenium or not, if not, then it calls the ChromeDriver directly. The test site includes some JavaScript to explicitly write to the console.log:

```
<?php

require_once (__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php');

use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome;

$javaPath = '"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath\\java.exe"';
$seleniumPath = '"'. __DIR__ . '\\..\\selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar"';

$chromeDriverPath = 'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe';
$site = 'http://mytestsite';

$seleniumPort = 4445;
$useSelenium = true;
$chromeDriverPathEnvVar = 'webdriver.chrome.driver';

putenv( $chromeDriverPathEnvVar .'='. $chromeDriverPath );

$chromeOptions = new Chrome\ChromeOptions();
$chromeOptions->addArguments( array( '--headless' ) );

$chromeCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$chromeCapabilities->setCapability( Chrome\ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $chromeOptions );
$chromeCapabilities->setCapability( 'loggingPrefs', ['browser' => 'ALL'] );

$selenium = null;

if ($useSelenium) {

    $descriptorspec = array(
        0 => array('pipe', 'r'),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
        1 => array('file', __DIR__ . '/selenium_log-' . date('Ymd-His').'_'. $seleniumPort . '-stdout.txt', 'a'),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
        2 => array('file', __DIR__ . '/selenium_log-' . date('Ymd-His').'_'. $seleniumPort . '-stderr.txt', 'a')   // stderr is a file to write to
    );

    $selenium_cmd = $javaPath .' -D'. $chromeDriverPathEnvVar .'="'. $chromeDriverPath .'" -jar '. $seleniumPath .' -port '. $seleniumPort; // If interested, add .' -debug';
    $selenium = proc_open( $selenium_cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null, array( 'bypass_shell' => true ) );

    $host = 'http://localhost:'. $seleniumPort .'/wd/hub'; // this is the default
    $chromeDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $chromeCapabilities );

} else {

    $chromeDriver = Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeDriver::start( $chromeCapabilities );
}

$chromeDriver->get( $site );

var_dump( $chromeDriver->manage()->getLog( 'browser' ) );

$chromeDriver->quit(); sleep(1);
$chromeDriver->action(); sleep(1);
$chromeDriver->close();

if ($useSelenium) {

    fclose( $pipes[0] );
    proc_terminate( $selenium );
    @pclose( $selenium );
}
```

Comment: that worked perfectly fine for me, thank You!

Answer (score 3):

I was banging my head against this for a while- getting an empty array returned from `$driver->manage()->getLog('browser');`.  Then I found [this github issue](https://github.com/symfony/panther/issues/339).  I changed
`$desiredCapabilities->setCapability('loggingPrefs', ['browser'=>'ALL']);` to
`$desiredCapabilities->setCapability('goog:loggingPrefs', ['browser'=>'ALL']);`.  The difference was adding in `goog:` before `loggingPrefs`.

After that, whammo, `$driver->manage()->getLog('browser');` returns a non-empty array =).